# flash's "useHandCursor = true" not working for Chrome on Mac

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, cursor, mouseevent

I'm developing a flash game using the default SimpleButton object for my buttons and the hand cursor is working just fine on PC Chrome and Firefox and Safari for Mac, but Chrome on Mac is not letting me swap the default cursor for the hand cursor.  I've even set useHandCursor to true for every button I add a click event to and am still getting nothing.

We've got no other rollover events, so it's important that the cursor switch.

Anyone else run into this and have a lil-fixy / workaround?

Comment: we ended up fixing this by putting in our own roll-over animation, not a huge deal but it still sucks.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding buttonMode="true" and mouseChildren="false"

Comment: I'm using SimpleButtons, so there is no buttonMode or mouseChildren variables to set.  Those come from Sprite, and it seems like setting those doesn't work for sprites in mac chrome either :(

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a known issue with Chrome on the mac, unfortunately. I've seen a number of other people complaining about it but no solutions:

http://groups.google.com/group/flashcodersny/browse_thread/thread/78b5687f3d03fe31?fwc=1&pli=1

http://twitter.com/bit101/status/10482050100

Comment: @fucrate: Looks like it's Adobe's/Chrome's problem, not yours. The good news is: it's out of your hands. The bad news is: it's out of your hands.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug in Chrome 5 for the Mac; it's already fixed in the Dev channel.